# Changing scaling factor of an axis in 2D plot in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I am using Octave 3.6.1 on Ubuntu (12.04). Plotting a sample data displays the following:
[image: Octave 2D Plot]

Is there a way to change the scaling factor on the x-axis to 2,4,.. instead of 5,10,15...
In general, how can I change the scaling factor of an axis in and 2D or 3D plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would post this as comment, but not enough rep...

anyway, read this documentation in matlab - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

you can specify a vector limit = [xmin xmax ymin ymax] and call axis(limit) to set the min/max values of the axes. They also have an example of that in the documentation.